# Screenshot sizes for publishing android app on Google Play

Tags: android, google-play, screenshot

On the developer's console when you go to publish your android application the screenshots are needed with the following specifications,
320 x 480, 480 x 800, 480 x 854,1280 x 720, 1280 x 800 24 bit PNG or JPEG (no alpha) Full bleed, no border in art.
Now on [this link](http://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1078870) it says, "You may upload up to 8 screenshots."
My questions is,

- What are the sizes for the last five screenshots? - The first three being - 320 x 480, 480 x 800, 480 x 854
- Is it 480 x 800 **OR** 480 x 854 for the second to eight screenshot or is it that second should be 480 x 800 and third should be 480 x 854 and fourth - eighth?
- Are the sizes 1280 x 720, 1280 x 800 only for tablets and are they optional?

Comment: for example for a phone screenshot 2160 x 3840

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It has to be any one of the given sizes and a minimum of 2 but up to 8 screenshots are accepted in Google Playstore.

Answer (score 35):

When I publish apps I use the following screenshot sizes:

**Phone: 1080 x 1920** I prepare 8 images with title, some fancy background and a screenshot inside a smartphone mockup. So it's more than a simple screenshot. It gives some nice branding and helps you to stand out from other apps out there.

**Tablet 7": 1200 x 1920** - I do actually a couple of raw screenshots of 7" emulator so that the user could know how the layout will appear on his device. No fancy design with titles etc.

**Tablet 10": 1800 x 2560** - same thing here, just a couple of raw screenshots.

all in `.png` format. 
Hope this helps.

Comment: Are TABLET screenshots required though, even for phone-only apps? Theres an asterisk bu tablet screenshots, so I am assuming they are required?

Answer (score 24):

- We require 2 screenshots.
- Use: Displayed on the details page for your application in Google
  Play.
- You may upload **up to 8 screenshots each** for phone, 7” tablet    and
  10” tablet.
- Specs: Minimum dimension: 320 pixels. Maximum dimension: 3840 pixels.
  The maximum dimension of your screenshot cannot be more than twice as
  long as the minimum dimension. You may use 24 bit PNG or JPEG image
  (no alpha). Full bleed, no border in art.
- We recommend adding screenshots of your app running on a 7" and 10"
  tablet. Go to ‘Store listing’ page in your Developer Console to add
  tablet apps screenshots.

https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/1078870?hl=en&ref_topic=2897459

Comment: I assume that if one wants the screenshots to be displayed quicker, size in MB also counts...
Oops, just realized the message was written more than 5 years ago... This Internet doesn't forget anything... :)

Comment: These settings are still actual.

Answer (score 14):

At last! I got the answer to this, the size to edit it in photoshop is: **379x674**

You are welcome

Answer (score 2):

You can upload up to 8 screenshots.  Those screenshots must be one of the dimensions (sizes) you listed; you can have multiple screenshots of the same dimensions.

Comment: If I provide all screenshots in all 3 dimensions will they all appear on the google play page at once (repeated)?

Comment: Yes they appear repeated. Most apps do it like that.

Answer (score 0):

The files need to be in a **JPEG** or **PNG** format of **24 bits**, in a **2:1 ratio if it is a portrait** and a **16:9 ratio for landscapes**. Be careful that if you go for different sizes: the maximum size should not be more than twice bigger than the minimum size.

Comment: 2:1 for portrait?